# Plotting a piecewise function

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, plot

I'm trying to learn to plot in latex, but I'm having a problem trying to find out which packages that are best to use in this situation, and I find it a bit of a learning curve.

Suppose you have the following function: 
[image: function]

I would like to know, how I could graph this in Latex. I have searched around and found out that you could use the PGF and tikz packages, and use the declare function, but I have problems with the intervals in which $x$ is defined

How would I approach this problem, as a complete newbie to graphing in Latex? 
I tried using a similiar post about it, and tried to plug in my intervals. My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    func(\x)= (\x \in [-\pi, -\frac{pi}{2}) * (0)   +
     and(\x \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}) * (\frac{\pi}{2}-|x|)     +
     and(\x \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]) * (0)
   ;
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$y$,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$x$,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Hi. I found a similiar post, and tried to just plug in the intervals, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261533/plotting-piecewise-function-using-declare-function?rq=1, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327221/1952

Comment: Which post? Please add the code you have so far to your question.

Comment: I added the code I tried. It just gives me a blank graph.

Comment: @Hatze to plot the function write `\addplot[<your-options>]{func(x)};` inside the `axis` environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of things you've gotten wrong. First of all, as marsupilam says in a comment, you have to plot the function as well, not just declare it.

Second, you can't use `\frac`, `\pi` etc. when declaring functions. They are macros intended for *typesetting* math, to do a calculation write it like e.g. `pi/2`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    func(\x)= (\x < -pi/2) * (0)   +
              and(\x >= -pi/2, \x < pi/2) * (pi/2-abs(\x))     +
              (\x >= pi/2) * (0)
   ;
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$y$,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=-pi:pi,samples=101, % added
]

\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: That makes sense, and I understand the logic behind the syntax. Just one last question; If I wanted more of the function to be drawn, how would I specify that?

Comment: @Hatze The `domain` setting defines the domain over which to plot the function, if that is what you meant.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I thank you very much for your help!

Comment: x >= -pi/2    should be replaced by    \x >= -pi/2

Comment: What about not equal to, in the func setup?

Comment: @Himanshu `!=`, as described in chapter 94.2 of the manual (unofficial HTML-version of that at https://tikz.dev/math-parsing#sec-94.2)