# Plotting piecewise function - not working, and not sure why!

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm plotting a graph with the following code: 
(also, I don't think **centering** is working either)

Before I made a modification to the give code:

[image]

The code:

```
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
    func(\x) = (\x < 0) * (2*\x) +
           and (\x >= 0) * (2*\x+1)
    ;}

\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
    ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$x$,
    domain=-5:5,samples=101, % added
]

\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The error:

```
/Users/rafaelvergnaud/Desktop/hw10.tex:103: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `Y'. The unreadable part was near 'Y'. (in '(2Y5.0e0]<0)*(2(2Y5.0e0]))+and(2Y5.0e0]>=0)*(2(2Y5.0e0])+1)+'). [\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};]
/Users/rafaelvergnaud/Desktop/hw10.tex:103: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `0'. The unreadable part was near '0'. (in '(2Y5.0e0]<0)*(2(2Y5.0e0]))+and(2Y5.0e0]>=0)*(2(2Y5.0e0])+1)+'). [\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};]
/Users/rafaelvergnaud/Desktop/hw10.tex:103: Missing number, treated as zero. [\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};]
/Users/rafaelvergnaud/Desktop/hw10.tex:103: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};]
/Users/rafaelvergnaud/Desktop/hw10.tex:103: Missing = inserted for \ifdim. [\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};]
/Users/rafaelvergnaud/Desktop/hw10.tex:103: Missing number, treated as zero. [\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};]
/Users/rafaelvergnaud/Desktop/hw10.tex:103: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};]
```

Comment: Well, your function has several issues. For instance, you suppressed all multiplication signs, have a trailing + at the end, and in the present form the and statement does not make sense. And whether or not \centering works will depend on the ambient document, which you do not disclose.

Comment: I'm using the exact same code as the answer given to the question posted here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373512/plotting-a-piecewise-function. I only altered the function definition.

Comment: Hey marmot! I was not going after you. Sorry if it seemed that way. I just wanted to refer you to the post that I got the code from, so I posted a link in the comment.

Comment: No worries! It's just that there are subtle but important differences between the two function declarations. You can't write 2(\x), use 2*\x instead, and has two arguments and you can't have a trailing +.

Comment: Hey, marmot! Thanks. I fixed and edited the post accordingly. However, the computer is still returning the build with errors!

Comment: Unfortunately "and" still has only one argument. I will be back at my computer in less than an hour and will give more feedback if no one else did so beforehand.

Comment: ok. Thanks marmot. :) Sorry again for the misunderstanding earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an attempt to answer your question.

- Even though it is usual in math to write `2x`, the common LaTeX parsers, which include the ones that come with Ti*k*Z and pstricks, do not understand that syntax, so you need to use `2*\x` (or `2*x` in the case of pfplots instead, but not for `declare function`).
- You forgot a closing `]` after `declare function`.
- `and` has two arguments but I actually would not use it here. Rather I'd use `ifthenelse`.

However, I am unsure which function you want to plot, so I added both.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
    func(\x) = (abs(\x) < 1) * (2*(1-abs(\x)));}] % added ]

\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
    ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$x$,
    domain=-5:5,samples=101, % added
]
\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{\texttt{\textbackslash centering} works in document classes like \texttt{article}, but
not (easily) in \texttt{standalone} because there is (a priori) nothing to be
centered against.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
    func(\x) = ifthenelse(\x<0,2*\x,2*\x+1);}] 

\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
    ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$f'(x)$,
    xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$x$,
    domain=-5:5,samples at={-5,-0.0001,0,5}, % added
]
\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{This is the function from your screen shot. I recommend using
\texttt{samples at} here because otherwise you will have to use a very large
number of samples. Alternatively, you could let the function jump by just
plotting two functions, i.e.\ having two \texttt{\textbackslash addplot}
commands, but probably you want to have the stretch with infinite slope.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud You're welcome!