# Piecewise Function in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to create a piecewise plot in tikzpicture. Trying to emulate the example from this answer [Plotting a piecewise function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373512/plotting-a-piecewise-function) didn't work for me, and I don't understand why this code isn't working.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
            func(\x)= (\x<=0) * ((0.5)*exp(\x))   +
            and(\x>0) * (1-(0.5)*exp(-\x))
            ;
        }
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, ytick={0,0.5,1}, ylabel=$F_{X-Y}(t)$,
        xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$t$,
        ]
        \addplot[blue, domain=-5:5, smooth]{func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome! You have an excess `and`. Use `func(\x)= (\x<=0) * ((0.5)*exp(\x))   +
            (\x>0) * (1-(0.5)*exp(-\x));`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Welcome! You call `and` with only one argument, and it seems to me (but I may be wrong) that you do not want an `and` at all. (You may also change the function to only use `abs` and `sign` functions, see the `afunc` definition.)

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
            func(\x)= (\x<=0) * ((0.5)*exp(\x))   +
            (\x>0) * (1-(0.5)*exp(-\x));
            afunc(\x)=0.5*(1+sign(\x)-sign(\x)*exp(-abs(\x)));
        }
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, ytick={0,0.5,1}, ylabel=$F_{X-Y}(t)$,
        xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$t$,
        ]
        \addplot[blue, domain=-5:5, smooth]{func(x)};
        \addplot[red, domain=-5:5, smooth,dashed,thick]{afunc(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the function may be approximated by a `tanh`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
            func(\x)= (\x<=0) * ((0.5)*exp(\x))   +
            (\x>0) * (1-(0.5)*exp(-\x));
        }
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, ytick={0,0.5,1}, ylabel=$F_{X-Y}(t)$,
        xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$t$,
        ]
        \addplot[blue, domain=-5:5, smooth]{func(x)};
        \addplot[red, domain=-5:5, smooth,dashed,thick]{0.5*tanh(x/1.5)+0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `afunc(\x)=0.5*(1+sign(\x)*(1-exp(-abs(\x))));` works too :-) . Nice answer (+1)

Comment: @Zarko Thanks! Yes, this is even simpler.

Comment: BTW, such function (without offset) is used as approximation of `sign˙ function in a realization of the sliding mode control (SMC). With it theoretical infinity switching frequency of the SMC is set to some reachable value of a used hardware.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks again! I am more familiar with `tanh`, which has an analytic continuation. It appears often in domain walls, kinks and quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Schrodinger's cat This works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Zarko good to know! Can Fourier Transform be used here to approximate tanh, too?

Comment: @Zarko Yes, it gives some hyperbolic cosecant function. Of course, if you have `exp(-|x|)` you get something like `1/(1+k^2)`, i.e. the propagator of a massive particle, which may be advantageous to use.

Comment: ups, now we are off-topic :-) ... Fourier transform in limits is possible (so far I din't try  calculate it). Regarding particle, I'm little bit familiar only with particle filters in signal processing (but no longer work on this domain) ;-)